# Swagger Spec for OpenID Connect

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

Since OpenID Connect uses HTTP, headers, query strings etc I would like to get a Swagger/OpenAPI specification as documentation. 
I have tried to find it but not successful.

Do you know where to find it?

/ Joacim

Comment: were you able to find good swagger spec for  OpenID Connect flows?

Comment: No I didn't fins any, I started to hack one myself but not complete nor working in Swagger UI. If you have any ideas, please let me know :)

Comment: here is my version of OAuth2 spec for Authorization code grant: https://github.com/fed239/oauth2-swagger/blob/master/oauth2-authorization_code.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source

> https://docs.gravitee.io/am/2.x/oidc/index.html

If you scroll down they have the Swagger UI up too

> https://docs.gravitee.io/am/2.x/oidc/index.html#tag/OpenID-Connect

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: >-
    Gravitee.io - Access Management - OpenID Connect API.
    Defines The OpenID Connect Endpoints exposed by AM server.
  version: 2.8.0
  title: Gravitee.io - Access Management - OpenID Connect API
  contact:
    email: contact@graviteesource.com
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html'
host: auth.gravitee.io
basePath: /{domain}/oidc
schemes:
- https
paths:
  /.well-known/openid-configuration:
    get:
      tags:
      - OpenID Connect
      summary: Get OpenID Provider configuration information
      description: Discovery endpoint used by OpenID Connect Relying Party to discover the End-User's OpenID Provider and obtain information needed to interact with it, including its OAuth 2.0 endpoint locations.
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The OpenID Provider Metadata values
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/OpenIDProviderMetadataResponse'
  /.well-known/jwks.json:
    get:
      tags:
      - OpenID Connect
      summary: Get JSON Web Key Set
      description: JWKS endpoint containing the public keys used by OpenID Connect Relying Party to verify any JWT issued by the authorization server.
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A JSON object that represents a set of JWKs
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/JWKSetResponse'
  /userinfo:
    get:
      tags:
      - OpenID Connect
      summary: Get claims about the authenticated End-User
      description: The UserInfo Endpoint is an OAuth 2.0 Protected Resource that returns Claims about the authenticated End-User.
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - in: header
        name: Authorization
        description: To obtain the requested Claims about the End-User, the Client makes a request to the UserInfo Endpoint using an Access Token obtained through OpenID Connect Authentication
        type: string
        required: true
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid Request
        '401':
          description: Invalid Token
        '200':
          description: Claims about the authenticated End-User
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/UserInfoResponse'
    post:
      tags:
      - OpenID Connect
      summary: Get claims about the authenticated End-User
      description: The UserInfo Endpoint is an OAuth 2.0 Protected Resource that returns Claims about the authenticated End-User.
      consumes:
      - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - in: formData
        name: access_token
        description: To obtain the requested Claims about the End-User, the Client makes a request to the UserInfo Endpoint using an Access Token obtained through OpenID Connect Authentication
        type: string
        required: true
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid Request
        '401':
          description: Invalid Token
        '200':
          description: Claims about the authenticated End-User
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/UserInfoResponse'
  /register:
    post:
      tags:
      - OpenID Connect
      summary: Register (create) a new client.
      description: The Dynamic Client Registration (dcr) Endpoint is an OAuth 2.0 Protected Resource through which a new Client registration can be requested.
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - in: header
        name: Authorization
        description: Bearer token obtained through client crendentials flow with as mandatory scope "dcr_admin". Token required unless open dynamic client registration is enabled.
        type: string
        required: false
      - in: body
        name: request
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/ClientRegistrationRequest'
        required: true
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid Request
        '401':
          description: Invalid Token
        '403':
          description: Registration forbidden
        '201':
          description: Claims about the registred client
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ClientRegistrationResponse'
  /register/{client_id}:
    get:
      tags:
      - OpenID Connect
      summary: Get a registred client.
      description: See information about a registred client.
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - in: header
        name: Authorization
        description: Bearer token obtained on the register process through the registration_access_token property giving access only to one client matching the client_id path parameter. An admin token can be also obtained through the client crendentials flow with as mandatory scope "dcr_admin".
        type: string
        required: true
      - in: path
        name: client_id
        type: string
        required: true
        description: ID of the client
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid Request
        '401':
          description: Invalid Token
        '403':
          description: Access forbidden
        '200':
          description: Claims about the registred client.
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ClientRegistrationResponse'
    patch:
      tags:
      - OpenID Connect
      summary: Patch a registred client.
      description: Update information about a registred client.
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - in: header
        name: Authorization
        description: Bearer token obtained on the register process through the registration_access_token property giving access only to one client matching the client_id path parameter. An admin token can be also obtained through the client crendentials flow with as mandatory scope "dcr_admin".
        type: string
        required: true
      - in: path
        name: client_id
        type: string
        required: true
        description: ID of the client
      - in: body
        name: request
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/ClientRegistrationRequest'
        required: true
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid Request
        '401':
          description: Invalid Token
        '403':
          description: Access forbidden
        '200':
          description: Claims about the updated client.
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ClientRegistrationResponse'
    delete:
      tags:
      - OpenID Connect
      summary: Delete a registred client.
      description: Delete a registred client.
      parameters:
      - in: header
        name: Authorization
        description: Bearer token obtained on the register process through the registration_access_token property giving access only to one client matching the client_id path parameter. An admin token can be also obtained through the client crendentials flow with as mandatory scope "dcr_admin".
        type: string
        required: true
      - in: path
        name: client_id
        type: string
        required: true
        description: ID of the client
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid Request
        '401':
          description: Invalid Token
        '403':
          description: Access forbidden
        '204':
          description: Client deleted
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ClientRegistrationResponse'
  /register/{client_id}/renew_secret:
    post:
      tags:
        - OpenID Connect
      summary: Renew the client secret of a registred client.
      description: Renew the client secret of a registred client.
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: Authorization
          description: Bearer token obtained on the register process through the registration_access_token property giving access only to one client matching the client_id path parameter. An admin token can be also obtained through the client crendentials flow with as mandatory scope "dcr_admin".
          type: string
          required: true
        - in: path
          name: client_id
          type: string
          required: true
          description: ID of the client
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid Request
        '401':
          description: Invalid Token
        '403':
          description: Access forbidden
        '200':
          description: Claims about the updated client.
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ClientRegistrationResponse'
securityDefinitions:
  client_auth:
    type: basic
    description: Base64(clientId:clientSecret)
definitions:
  OpenIDProviderMetadataResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      issuer:
        type: string
        description: REQUIRED. URL using the https scheme with no query or fragment component that the OP asserts as its Issuer Identifier
      authorization_endpoint:
        type: string
        description: REQUIRED. URL of the OP's OAuth 2.0 Authorization Endpoint
      token_endpoint:
        type: string
        description: URL of the OP's OAuth 2.0 Token Endpoint
      userinfo_endpoint:
        type: string
        description: RECOMMENDED. URL of the OP's UserInfo Endpoint
      jwks_uri:
        type: string
        description: REQUIRED. URL of the OP's JSON Web Key Set [JWK] document.
      registration_endpoint:
        type: string
        description: RECOMMENDED. URL of the OP's Dynamic Client Registration Endpoint
      scopes_supported:
        type: string
        description: RECOMMENDED. JSON array containing a list of the OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749] scope values that this server supports
      response_types_supported:
        type: string
        description: REQUIRED. JSON array containing a list of the OAuth 2.0 response_type values that this OP supports
      response_modes_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the OAuth 2.0 response_mode values that this OP supports
      grant_types_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the OAuth 2.0 Grant Type values that this OP supports
      acr_values_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the Authentication Context Class References that this OP supports
      subject_types_supported:
        type: string
        description: REQUIRED. JSON array containing a list of the Subject Identifier types that this OP supports
      id_token_signing_alg_values_supported:
        type: string
        description: REQUIRED. JSON array containing a list of the JWS signing algorithms (alg values) supported by the OP for the ID Token to encode the Claims in a JWT
      id_token_encryption_alg_values_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWE encryption algorithms (alg values) supported by the OP for the ID Token to encode the Claims in a JWT
      id_token_encryption_enc_values_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWE encryption algorithms (enc values) supported by the OP for the ID Token to encode the Claims in a JWT
      userinfo_signing_alg_values_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWS signing algorithms (alg values) [JWA] supported by the UserInfo Endpoint to encode the Claims in a JWT
      userinfo_encryption_alg_values_supported:
        type: string
        description: ROPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWE encryption algorithms (alg values) [JWA] supported by the UserInfo Endpoint to encode the Claims in a JWT
      userinfo_encryption_enc_values_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWE encryption algorithms (enc values) [JWA] supported by the UserInfo Endpoint to encode the Claims in a JWT
      request_object_signing_alg_values_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWS signing algorithms (alg values) supported by the OP for Request Objects
      request_object_encryption_alg_values_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWE encryption algorithms (alg values) supported by the OP for Request Objects
      request_object_encryption_enc_values_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWE encryption algorithms (enc values) supported by the OP for Request Objects
      token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of Client Authentication methods supported by this Token Endpoint
      token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWS signing algorithms (alg values) supported by the Token Endpoint for the signature on the JWT
      display_values_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the display parameter values that the OpenID Provider supports
      claim_types_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the Claim Types that the OpenID Provider supports
      claims_supported:
        type: string
        description: RECOMMENDED. JSON array containing a list of the Claim Names of the Claims that the OpenID Provider MAY be able to supply values for
      service_documentation:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. URL of a page containing human-readable information that developers might want or need to know when using the OpenID Provider
      claims_locales_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. Languages and scripts supported for values in Claims being returned, represented as a JSON array of BCP47 [RFC5646] language tag values
      ui_locales_supported:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. Languages and scripts supported for the user interface, represented as a JSON array of BCP47 [RFC5646] language tag values
      claims_parameter_supported:
        type: boolean
        description: OPTIONAL. Boolean value specifying whether the OP supports use of the claims parameter, with true indicating support. If omitted, the default value is false
      request_parameter_supported:
        type: boolean
        description: OPTIONAL. Boolean value specifying whether the OP supports use of the request parameter, with true indicating support. If omitted, the default value is false
      request_uri_parameter_supported:
        type: boolean
        description: OPTIONAL. Boolean value specifying whether the OP supports use of the request_uri parameter, with true indicating support. If omitted, the default value is true
      require_request_uri_registration:
        type: boolean
        description: OPTIONAL. Boolean value specifying whether the OP requires any request_uri values used to be pre-registered using the request_uris registration parameter
      op_policy_uri:
        type: string
        description: OPTIONAL. URL that the OpenID Provider provides to the person registering the Client to read about the OP's requirements on how the Relying Party can use the data provided by the OP
      op_tos_uri:
        type: boolean
        description: OPTIONAL. URL that the OpenID Provider provides to the person registering the Client to read about OpenID Provider's terms of service
  UserInfoResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      sub:
        type: string
        description: Subject - Identifier for the End-User at the Issuer
      name:
        type: string
        description: End-User's full name in displayable form including all name parts, possibly including titles and suffixes, ordered according to the End-User's locale and preferences
      given_name:
        type: string
        description: Given name(s) or first name(s) of the End-User
      family_name:
        type: string
        description: Surname(s) or last name(s) of the End-User
      middle_name:
        type: string
        description: Middle name(s) of the End-User
      nickname:
        type: string
        description: Casual name of the End-User that may or may not be the same as the given_name
      preferred_username:
        type: string
        description: Shorthand name by which the End-User wishes to be referred to at the RP, such as janedoe or j.doe
      profile:
        type: string
        description: URL of the End-User's profile page
      picture:
        type: string
        description: URL of the End-User's profile picture
      website:
        type: string
        description: URL of the End-User's Web page or blog
      email:
        type: string
        description: End-User's preferred e-mail address
      email_verified:
        type: boolean
        description: User at the time the verification was performed
      gender:
        type: string
        description: End-User's gender
      birthdate:
        type: string
        description: End-User's birthday, represented as an ISO 8601:2004 [ISO8601‑2004] YYYY-MM-DD format
      zoneinfo:
        type: string
        description: String from zoneinfo [zoneinfo] time zone database representing the End-User's time zone
      locale:
        type: string
        description: End-User's locale, represented as a BCP47 [RFC5646] language tag
      phone_number:
        type: string
        description: End-User's preferred telephone number
      phone_number_verified:
        type: boolean
        description: User at the time the verification was performed
      address:
        type: string
        description: End-User's preferred postal address
      updated_at:
        type: integer
        description: Time the End-User's information was last updated
  JWKSetResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      keys:
        type: array
        description: The value of the "keys" parameter is an array of JWK values
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/JWKResponse'
  JWKResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      kty:
        type: string
        description: The "kty" (key type) parameter identifies the cryptographic algorithm family used with the key, such as "RSA" or "EC"
      use:
        type: string
        description: The "use" (public key use) parameter identifies the intended use of the public key
      key_ops:
        type: string
        description: The "key_ops" (key operations) parameter identifies the operation(s) for which the key is intended to be used
      alg:
        type: string
        description: The "alg" (algorithm) parameter identifies the algorithm intended for use with the key
      kid:
        type: string
        description: The "kid" (key ID) parameter is used to match a specific key
      x5u:
        type: string
        description: The "x5u" (X.509 URL) parameter is a URI [RFC3986] that refers to a resource for an X.509 public key certificate or certificate chain [RFC5280]
      x5c:
        type: string
        description: The "x5c" (X.509 certificate chain) parameter contains a chain of one or more PKIX certificates [RFC5280]
      x5t:
        type: string
        description: The "x5t" (X.509 certificate SHA-1 thumbprint) parameter is a base64url-encoded SHA-1 thumbprint (a.k.a. digest) of the DER encoding of an X.509 certificate [RFC5280]
      x5t#S256:
        type: string
        description: The "x5t#S256" (X.509 certificate SHA-256 thumbprint) parameter is a base64url-encoded SHA-256 thumbprint (a.k.a. digest) of the DER encoding of an X.509 certificate [RFC5280]
  ClientRegistrationRequest:
    type: object
    required:
    - redirect_uris
    properties:
      redirect_uris:
        type: array
        description: REQUIRED. Array of Redirection URI values used by the Client. One of these registered Redirection URI values MUST exactly match the redirect_uri parameter value used in each Authorization Request
        items:
          type: string
      response_types:
        type: array
        description: JSON array containing a list of the OAuth 2.0 response_type values that the Client is declaring that it will restrict itself to using. If omitted, the default is that the Client will use only the code Response Type.
        items:
          type: string
      grant_types:
        type: array
        description: JSON array containing a list of the OAuth 2.0 Grant Types that the Client is declaring that it will restrict itself to using. Values used by OpenID Connect are authorization_code, implicit and refresh_token
        items:
          type: string
      application_type:
        type: string
        description: Kind of the application. The default, if omitted, is web. The defined values are native or web.
      contacts:
        type: array
        description: Array of e-mail addresses of people responsible for this Client. This might be used by some providers to enable a Web user interface to modify the Client information.
        items:
          type: string
      client_name:
        type: string
        description: Name of the Client to be presented to the End-User.
      logo_uri:
        type: string
        description: URL that references a logo for the Client application.
      client_uri:
        type: string
        description: URL of the home page of the Client. The value of this field MUST point to a valid Web page.
      policy_uri:
        type: string
        description: URL that the Relying Party Client provides to the End-User to read about the how the profile data will be used.
      tos_uri:
        type: string
        description: URL that the Relying Party Client provides to the End-User to read about the Relying Party's terms of service.
      jwks_uri:
        type: string
        description: URL for the Client's JSON Web Key Set [JWK] document.
      jwks:
        $ref: '#/definitions/JWKSetResponse'
        description: Client's JSON Web Key Set [JWK] document, passed by value. The semantics of the jwks parameter are the same as the jwks_uri parameter, other than that the JWK Set is passed by value, rather than by reference.
      sector_identifier_uri:
        type: string
        description: URL using the https scheme to be used in calculating Pseudonymous Identifiers by the OP. The URL references a file with a single JSON array of redirect_uri values.
      subject_type:
        type: string
        description: subject_type requested for responses to this Client. The subject_types_supported Discovery parameter contains a list of the supported subject_type values for this server. Valid types include pairwise and public.
      id_token_signed_response_alg:
        type: string
        description: JWS alg algorithm [JWA] REQUIRED for signing the ID Token issued to this Client. The default, if omitted, is RS256. The public key for validating the signature is provided by retrieving the JWK Set referenced by the jwks_uri element from OpenID Connect Discovery 1.0 [OpenID.Discovery].
      id_token_encrypted_response_alg:
        type: string
        description: JWE alg algorithm [JWA] REQUIRED for encrypting the ID Token issued to this Client. If this is requested, the response will be signed then encrypted, with the result being a Nested JWT, as defined in [JWT]. The default, if omitted, is that no encryption is performed.
      id_token_encrypted_response_enc:
        type: string
        description: JWE enc algorithm [JWA] REQUIRED for encrypting the ID Token issued to this Client. If id_token_encrypted_response_alg is specified, the default for this value is A128CBC-HS256. When id_token_encrypted_response_enc is included, id_token_encrypted_response_alg MUST also be provided.
      userinfo_signed_response_alg:
        type: string
```

cut off at 30K character limit